# Pair-wise mean value of upper and lower triangle in r

Tags: r, matrix

How to calculate the mean value of a matrix like this?

I.e. pair-wise mean of V2_V1(0.194903974) and V1_V2(0.029498525) and so on (without the diagonal) and the result written as a list. The lower part of the code section is the expected result.

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
V1  1   0.194903974 0.039646321 0.13510173  0.403593839 0.040216771 0.247385434
V2  0.029498525 1   0.007885459 0.072393697 0.051759119 0.008144471 0.112770703
V3  0.149194991 0.196064401 1   0.270125224 0.201073345 0.936314848 0
V4  0.117195876 0.414927835 0.062268041 1   0.207505155 0.064494845 0.507134021
V5  0.308256481 0.261201075 0.040810399 0.182702781 1   0.057802629 0.207174497
V6  0.125519288 0.167952522 0.776557864 0.232047478 0.23620178  1   0
V7  0.130970957 0.394473247 0   0.30950823  0.143604973 0   1


    V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
V1                          
V2  mean                        
V3  mean    mean                    
V4  mean    mean    mean                
V5  mean    mean    mean    mean            
V6  mean    mean    mean    mean    mean        
V7  mean    mean    mean    mean    mean    mean
```

Comment: Try `mean(m1[upper.tri(m1)])` and `mean(m1[lower.tri(m1)])`  If you need the diag elements, use `diag = TRUE`  If you need it as a `list` i..e `list(mean(m1[upper.tri(m1)]), mean(m1[lower.tri(m1)]))`

Comment: I see. And if I want the ((V2-V1)+(V1-V2))/2 and so on?

Comment: But that is another question

Comment: You are correct. My question is not precise enough

Comment: Isn't the mean of `V1-V2` and `V2-V1` the same?

Comment: The expected output is not clear.  You said that we need to get the mean of upper and lower triangle.  So, what are those means in the expected output?

Comment: doesn't `(V2-V1)+(V1-V2)` == 0

Comment: ahh, re edit:  maybe just `(mat + t(mat))/2`

Comment: Yes indeed. Then either the upper or lower should be converted to a list.

Comment: well, the upper == lower. Can you show what the list should look like please. Though maybe `out = (x + t(x))/2 ; split(out[lower.tri(out)], row(out)[lower.tri(out)])`

Comment: yes. taht solution also worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we need pairwise `mean`

```
m2 <- matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(m1), nrow = nrow(m1))
m2[lower.tri(m2)] <- rowMeans(cbind(m1[upper.tri(m1, diag = FALSE)], 
                                m1[lower.tri(m1, diag = FALSE)]))
m2
#           [,1]      [,2]       [,3]      [,4]      [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]         NA        NA         NA        NA        NA   NA   NA
#[2,] 0.11220125        NA         NA        NA        NA   NA   NA
#[3,] 0.09442066 0.2998291         NA        NA        NA   NA   NA
#[4,] 0.06254067 0.2333435 0.03520626        NA        NA   NA   NA
#[5,] 0.22167911 0.2311372 0.48856262 0.2150441        NA   NA   NA
#[6,] 0.09895649 0.1877288 0.42052635 0.1724091 0.3716679   NA   NA
#[7,] 0.20054809 0.2173450 0.02890131 0.1547541 0.1753897    0   NA
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. The result should give all of the combinations in the lower tri.

Comment: @user3655531  Updated the post

Comment: With this addition l1 <- as.list(m2[lower.tri(m2)]) I got it out in a list format. Thanks all

Comment: An interesting next thing, would be to retain the column and and row name combination in the output. But that is another question.

Comment: @user3655531  How do you want to return or name it

Comment: Like: V1_V2, V1_V3, V1_V4 and so on

Comment: @user3655531  You can try `do.call(paste, c(subset(expand.grid(rownames(m1), colnames(m1))[2:1], Var1 != Var2), sep= "_"))`

Comment: Thanks. But doesn't that give the combos of both the upper AND the lower tri?

Comment: @user3655531  Yes, it does give and from that you can subset the ones that are not needed

Comment: @user3655531  Or use `outer` i..e `nm1 <- outer(rownames(m1), colnames(m1), FUN = paste, sep="_");
 nm1[upper.tri(nm1)]`